# Tap on the button and open searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, button, uisearchbar

I have a tableView with `searchBar` implemented. In the top of this, I have a button, which should `open searchBar with keyboard`. Here is how it should look like: [image: User tap here]

[image: Open search bar]

So, when `user tap on this button`, it `should open the searchBar and user can start typing something`. Here is my `search methods`:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        guard !searchText.isEmpty else { filteredActiveState = activeStates; tableView.reloadData(); return }

        searching = true
        //typeView.isHidden = false

        filteredActiveState = activeStates.filter({ titleName -> Bool in
            return titleName.title!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.isHidden = true
        channelLbl.isHidden = false
        searchButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
        typeView.isHidden = true
        //searchBar.endEditing(true)
        //searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
```

*`Here is code for this button`*:

```
@IBAction func searchBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        searchBar.isHidden = false
        channelLbl.isHidden = true
        searchButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you did `searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` inside your `func searchBtnPressed` ?